# Where can I download `idndlpackage.EXE`?

Tags: windows-xp, broken-links, legacy-app

Supporting Internationalized Domain Name (IDN) on Windows XP requires "Microsoft Internationalized Domain Name (IDN) Mitigation APIs", whose file name is `idndlpackage.EXE`, but the [download link](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=AD6158D7-DDBA-416A-9109-07607425A815&displaylang=en) is now unavailable on the Microsoft website. Where else can I download it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`idndlpackage.EXE` is an archive containing 3 arch specific installers = but you only need **`idndl.x86.exe`**, which was sometimes added with redist packages with some app installs.

Search on google shows this working link:
 `MTA San Andreas\redist\idndl.x86.exe` (575 KB):
https://github.com/multitheftauto/mtasa-blue/blob/master/Shared/data/MTA%20San%20Andreas/redist/idndl.x86.exe